# Symfony, preemptively hint/display validation constraint message in a form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation, twig

when I have a form and some constraint rules there, like `max value` or `LessThanOrEqual`, how can I display this rule conditions so that the user know what data format the input accepts?

**I would imagine to display the same message that appears after failed validation (after form submit) to be visible all the time, somewhere near respective `<input>`**

MORE INFO

I have this in respective `buildForm`, and as you can see the `LessThanOrEqual` have dynamic possible values. So it would be nice to always aknowledge the user about the max value that can be entered.

```
    $builder
        ->add('amount', null, [
            'constraints' => [
                new LessThanOrEqual($maxValue)
            ]
        ])
```

I know I can use **help** attribute, but It would be kind of redundant to define the translation text again, because all the validation rules are already set up. So it would be nice to just display the same message, that will appear after submitting the form with failed validation. So in my example:

> This value should be less than or equal to {{ compared_value }}

Thank you

EDIT: 
It would be partialy solved by real time javascript validation which would validate and inform the user in real time, just use some javascript (jQuery,...) plugin.

But, a simple text message displayed next to an input (informing about the validation rules) would be nice too - that would not be solved by this javascript solution.

EDIT 2:
In my twig view is just basic, nothing special:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <button class="btn btn-success">{{ button_label|default('Save'|trans) }}</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: help exists and you should use it.

Comment: You could read the value of the `message` property on the constraint, but won't be interpolated if you just assign it as the `help` text I don't think, you'd have to do it yourself.

Comment: Can u edit your questions and add the code of the view page? (the code where u have `form_start` ... `form_end`)

Comment: I edited the post and added code from the twig view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since symfony 4.3 you can use 'help_translation_parameters', so this should work.

```
    $constraint = new LessThanOrEqual(7); // create constraint
    $builder
        ->add('amount', null, [
            'constraints' => [
                $constraint
            ],
            'help' => $constraint->message,
            'help_translation_parameters' => ['{{ compared_value }}' => $constraint->value]
        ])
    ;
```

Comment: I tried and tit works. Awesome. But, the problem is with translation. I have validation messages in validators.csxlf, but amount is translated in different translatino file. I know just about translation_domain attribute, which unfortunately effects both. Can I translate one with one translation domain and help with different domain?

Comment: You can autowire TranslatorInterface in constructor and use it for translating help attribute. 'help' => $this->translator->trans($constraint->message, ['{{ compared_value }}' => $constraint->value], 'validators')

Comment: I tried and it works without problems. Again. Thank you @fbuchlak